# When you have a multilevel list [python], how does the point of reference change in that list?

Tags: python, list, slice

So for example, you have:

```
a = [1,2]

b = [a,3]

c = b[:]

a[0] = 7

b[1] = 8

print c
```

You get `[[7, 2], 3]`

Why does `3` not get changed to `8`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fundamental principle, as mentioned by others, is that you are doing a "shallow copy" when you assign `c`.

To elaborate, you have this:

```
a = [1,2]
# a = list(1,2) at address AAA

b = [a, 3]
# b = list( [REFERENCE to AAA], 3) at address BBB

c = b[:]
# c = NEW list( b[0], b[1] ) at address CCC
# c = list( [REFERENCE to AAA], 3) at address CCC

a[0] = 7
# change item at AAA, offset [0], to 7
# 'b' points to AAA, so it will see change
# 'c' points to AAA, so it will see change

b[1] = 8
# change item at BBB, offset [1], to 8
# 'a' doesn't know about this, so it doesn't care.
# 'c' doesn't point to BBB, so it doesn't see the change.

print c
# Prints CCC offset [0], which refers to the AAA list, as changed,
# then prints CCC offset [1], which is still 3.
```